# Water glasses and coffee cups: Do they "turn over" or "flip over"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I hit a glass so it "turns over", can I then say I accidentally flipped it over?

I managed to spill coffee all over me today. I see that dictionaries suggest "flip over", but just wanted to get it confirmed. And what about "turn over"?

Comment: I would use "tip over".

Comment: "Tip over" or even "spill over" could work, the latter especially if you're focusing on the liquid. "Flip over" technically works but colloquially implies a more dramatic action, such as the glass spinning in the air instead of just falling straight on its side.

Comment: Better yet is [**overturn**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overturn).  I agree with Alexander: "flip over" implies going completely upside-down.

Comment: @Alexander Referring to the liquid, "spill over" would imply that the liquid turned some way, which they don't do. The action of the liquid is different from the glass. "The beer mug tipped over, and the beer *spilled* onto the table."

Answer (score 2):

To **flip over** means to make the up side the down side. Two opposite sides are involved.

> Flip the playing card over.
>
> Flip the pancakes over now, or they'll get too dark.

A glass has opposite ends, not opposite sides, so it would be odd to use **flip over**.

You could say that you **knocked it over** or **tipped it over**.

> I accidentally knocked over the glass with my elbow.
>
> I accidentally knocked the glass over with by elbow.